# Case mismatch error in Symfony 3.0.2

Tags: php, doctrine, case-sensitive, symfony

I am getting the following error in my application:

"Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: PeriscopeBundle\Entity\agency vs PeriscopeBundle\Entity\Agency"

I can't seem to figure out the source of the problem. I'm not sure how/where 'agency' is loaded within the application.

If I change the class name to 'agency' the application works. Can anyone point me in the right direction to debug/solve this issue pls?

Comment: Check your doctrine mappings.  Better yet, just do a case sensitive search for agency.  And make sure you clear your cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed the steps @Cerad mentioned in his comment before posting my question but I probably didn't have enough coffee at the time.

It was only after going through the steps a third time I noticed that I had incorrectly put 'agency' instead of Agency in the following annotation.

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Agency")
```